# How to check if classes have changed in Java?

Tags: java, serialization

I have made a large computation based on a dataset and some Java classes. The result is stored in a object. Now I would like to serialize this object and store it on disk, so that I don't have to do the computation every time again. The problem is that the computation should be redone if either the dataset changes or classes are added / removed from a certain package or the source code of at least one class in this package changes.

First, how can I check if the source code of at least one class in a specific packages has changed or classes are added / removed in the package since the last serialization of the object?

Second, how can I check if the dataset on disk has changed since the last serialization of the object? The dataset ist just a normal file.

Comment: You could create some kind of log file, protocolling the classes present in a package (this should be possible by inspecting the classpaths), as well as the date your program last read the object-file. Those information should be sufficient to determine whether you have to re-run your computation.

Comment: To check something has changed you need to write the previous state somewhere and later compare it to the current state.

Comment: By "classes have changed in Java" means you mean somebody changed source code and re-compiled them so the .class files changed?

Comment: @svasa Yes I mean that the source code is changed.

Comment: add a build-id in your production script, and serialize this build-id with your data ?